# Emptying array inside loop while using push in PERL

Tags: arrays, perl

I am writing a subroutine that prints an array of non redundant elements from another array.

This code is inside my subroutine.

```
foreach (@old_table) { push(@new_table, $_) unless ($seen{$_}++); }
print "@new_table" . "\n";
```

Then i call my subroutine in a loop inside my main program, for the first iteration it is OK and my new table contains one occurrence  of my old table.
But after that `@new_table` keeps elements from past iterations and the print result is false.

I tried emptying `@new_table` inside my subroutine like this

```
@new_table = ();
foreach (@old_table) { push(@new_table, $_) unless ($seen{$_}++); }
print "@new_table" . "\n";
```

But then my `@new_table` becomes empty in all iterations except for the first one.

What is the problem with this and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to incorrect scoping, you're reusing the `@new_table` and `%seen` of previous passes. Create these just before the loop.

```
my @new_table;
my %seen;
foreach (@old_table) { push(@new_table, $_) unless ($seen{$_}++); }
print "@new_table" . "\n";
```

This can be simplified to

```
my %seen;
my @new_table = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @old_table;
print "@new_table\n";
```

You can also use

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );

my @new_table = uniq(@old_table);
print "@new_table\n";
```

---

You are using `use strict; use warnings;`, right? If not, you should be. Always.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `uniq` from `List::MoreUtils` to remove redundant elements.

```
my @new_table = uniq(@old_table);
```

To quote from perldoc

> uniq LIST
>   distinct LIST
>
> Returns a new list by stripping duplicate values in LIST. The order of elements in the returned list is the same as in LIST. In
>   scalar context, returns
>              the number of unique elements in LIST.
>
> ```
>            my @x = uniq 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4; # returns 1 2 3 5 4
>            my $x = uniq 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4; # returns 5
> ```